# Check and explain whether X is compact in three topologies provided in the figure.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

[image]

In which of the three topologies is X compact?

Below is the way I did....

[image]

[image]

[image]

In the 1st screenshot, I showed that $X$ is compact in $T_s$, in the 2nd screenshot I showed that it is not compact in railroad metric $T_r$ and in the 3rd screenshot, I showed that it is not compact in $T_c$.

Can someone verify my proof and let me know if this looks good. If there is anything that can be changed for better style and notation, don't hesitate to let me know. Appreciate your help & support.

Answer (score 1):

$(1)$ is correct, though it would be better to show explicitly that $X$ is a closed subset of $\Bbb R^2$ in the usual topology. Once you’ve done that, though, there’s no need to work as hard as you did: it immediately follows that $X$ is a compact subset and hence a compact subspace of $\Bbb R^2$ in the usual topology, and $\langle X,T_s\rangle$ is precisely that subspace.

You are correct in thinking that $\langle X,T_r\rangle$ and $\langle X,T_c\rangle$ are not compact, but there are serious problems with both of your arguments. In $(2$) the set $B\left(\langle 1,0\rangle,\sqrt2+\frac12\right)\in\mathscr{O}$ already covers $X$, so $\mathscr{O}$ does have a finite subcover. And in $(3)$ **none** of the sets $S_n$ is open in $T_c$: $S_n$ is open if and only if $S_n\cap S_k$ is open in $S_k$ for every $k$, but $S_n\cap S_{n+1}=\{v\}$, which is not open in $S_{n+1}$.

There is actually an easy way to show that $\langle X,T_r\rangle$ and $\langle X,T_c\rangle$ are not compact using the result in my answer to your question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3642000/how-are-the-three-topologies-on-x-related-to-each-other-in-terms-of-coarser-and). All you need is your answer to $(1)$ and the following easy result:

**Theorem:** Let $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ be a compact Hausdorff space, and let $\tau'$ be a topology on $X$ strictly finer than $\tau$ (i.e., $\tau\subsetneqq\tau'$). Then $\langle X,\tau'\rangle$ is not compact.

**Proof:** Consider the identity map $\iota:X\to X$ as a function from $\langle X,\tau'\rangle$ to $\langle X,\tau\rangle$. Since $\tau'$ is finer than $\tau$, $\iota$ is continuous. Suppose that $\langle X,\tau'\rangle$ is compact, and let $F\subseteq X$ be $\tau'$-closed; then $F$ is compact, so $F=\iota[F]$ is compact in $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ and therefore also $\tau$-closed. Thus, $\iota$ is a closed, continuous bijection and hence a homeomorphism, contradicting the hypothesis that $\tau'\ne\tau$. It follows that $\langle X,\tau'\rangle$ cannot be compact. $\dashv$

Comment: For (1), how do I show that $X$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R^{2}}$ in the usual topology? By showing that its complement is open? Also, we know that a closed subset of a compact space is compact so will it be ideal to use that? I guess if we use that then we dont have to show that its a closed subset. I didnt understand ur rest of the arguments for (2) and (3), can you pls elaborate more using examples and computations ?

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun: Yes, you can show that its complement is open by showing how to find an open ball about each point of the complement that misses $X$. Of course that depends on exactly where the point is, and depending on your audience, it may be enough to give a qualitative description. E.g., for a point $p$ between $S_n$ and $S_{n+1}$ for some $n\ge 1$, it’s reasonably clear even without computational details that there is a positive $\epsilon$ small enough that $B(p,\epsilon$ is disjoint from $X$. I don’t know what more I can say about your errors in $(2)$ and $(3)$. If you actually draw ...

Comment: ... the set $B\left(\langle 1,0\rangle,\sqrt2+\frac12\right)$, for instance, you’ll see that it contains all of $X$, and since it’s in your open cover $\mathscr{O}$, that cover **does** have a finite subcover. And I gave a complete explanation of why the sets $S_n$ are not open in $T_c$: they don’t satisfy the definition. If you mean my argument that $T_r$ and $T_c$ are not compact, it’s immediate from the Theorem and the fact that $T_r$ and $T_c$ are both strictly finer than $T_s$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott  got your argument or more specifically the counter example which shows flaws in my proof. However, I do have some questions for u abt the theorem and proof which u posted....u said F=ι[F] , whats this? Also, u said that it is a closed continuous bijection, how r u saying that?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott.....In the plane $\mathbb{R^{2}}$, the set {x × y|x ≥ 0 and y ≥ 0} is closed, because its complement is the union of the two sets (∞, 0) × R and R × (−∞, 0), each of which is a product of open sets of $\mathbb{R}$ and is, therefore, open in $\mathbb{R^{2}}$, will this argument work for showing that $X$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R^{2}}$ in the usual topology ? Kindly check and let me know.

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun: $\iota$ is the identity map, so $\iota(x)=x$ for all $x\in X$, and therefore $\iota[F]=F$ for any subset $F$ of $X$. It’s continuous, because if $U\in\tau$, then $\iota^{-1}[U]=U\in\tau'$, since $\tau\subseteq\tau'$. I showed that it’s a closed map by showing that if $F$ is $\tau'$-closed, then $\iota[F]$, which is just the same set $F$, is $\tau$-closed. And every closed, continuous bijection is a homeomorphism: the fact that it’s a bijection means that it has an inverse, and the fact that it’s closed means that the inverse is continuous.

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun: Your argument in your last comment is part of showing that $X$ is closed in $\Bbb R^2$, but it’s far from being complete: you’ve shown only that **part** of its complement is open. You can get more by observing that $\{\langle x,y\rangle\in\Bbb R^2:x+y>1\}$ is open; then you have to worry only about the points inside the triangle with vertices $\langle 0,0\rangle,\langle 1,0\rangle$, and $\langle 0,1\rangle$ that are not in $X$. One way to do this is to see that for $n\ge 1$ $$\{\langle x,y\rangle:nx+y<1\text{ and }(n+1)x+y>1\text{ and }y>0\}$$ is open: it’s the open triangle ...

Comment: ... between $S_n$ and $S_{n+1}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I got your point now....thanks a lot for this. But u said "using the result in my answer to your question here", which one should I use? "We conclude that Ts⫋Tr⫋Tc", this one ?

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun: Yes, the fact that $T_s$ is strictly weaker than the other two topologies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107195/discussion-between-math-is-fun-and-brian-m-scott).