# In which of the three topologies is X connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

[image]

In which of the three topologies is X connected?

Below is how I did it but I am not sure, hence it will be great if someone helps me in this.

1. $T_s$ is the Subspace topology obtained from $\mathbb{R^2}$ since each $S_n$ is a Connected Subspace in $\mathbb{R^2}$ and $S_n \cap S_{n+1}$ $\neq$ $\emptyset$ $\forall n$. So, the unions of $S_n$ is connected Subspace of $\mathbb{R^2}$.
2. Since $T_s$ is finer than $T_r$ and $(X,T_s)$ is connected which implies $(X,T_r)$ is Connected.

3.In $T_c$ topology, each $S_n$ is open subset and $S_0$ \ {$v$} is also open as {$v$} is a Closed subset in $X$. Hence, $X = U_n$ = $S_n \cup S_o$ \ {$v$}. So $X$ is not connected in this topology.

I know that I have the right idea somewhere but I am not sure how to explain it better by showing all the calculations. Will be great if someone helps me on this. Appreciate your support & help.

Comment: $T_s$ is the *coarsest* of the three topologies; both of the other two are finer than $T_s$. See my answer to [your earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3642000/how-are-the-three-topologies-on-x-related-to-each-other-in-terms-of-coarser-and). A set $S_n$ is not open in $T_c$, because if $m\ne n$ we have $S_n\cap S_m=\{v\}$, which is not open in $S_m$. Try showing instead that $\langle X,T_c\rangle$ **is** connected. HINT: Consider what an open set containing $v$ must also contain.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Can u pls help me in this question? I know from the answers to my previous questions that $T_s$ is coarser than $T_r$ and not finer. So that's where I made a mistake. However, I am not sure how to show explicitly that $(X, T_r)$ and $(X, T_c)$ is not connected.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Sorry man, I said its not connected. It should be connected.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Show that $(X, T_c)$ is connected....We had a definition in connected spaces that says: Let X be a space. We say that X is separated iff( if and only if) there exist nonempty open sets U and V in X such that X = $U \cup V$ and $U \cup V$ = $\emptyset$. If there are such open sets, then we call X = $U \cup V$ a separation of X. We say X is connected if there does not exist a separation of X. Using this to this problem, we can say that for 2 non empty open sets $U$ and $V$, we have $U$ open in $T_c$ iff $U \cap S_n$ is open in each $S_n$............

Comment: ..........similarly, V is open in $T_c$ iff $V \cap S_n$ is open in each $S_n$. Therefore, when we take intersection of $U \cap S_n$ and $V \cap S_n$, it will give us $S_n \cap (V \cap U)$, and as we know that  $U \cap S_n$ and $V \cap S_n$ are non-empty therefore their intersection will also be a non empty set. Since its a non empty set, therefore we can say that $(X, T_c)$ is connected/not separated. Does this entire argument look good ?

Comment: It’s the right idea, but it needs a little work. I would argue like this. Suppose that $U$ and $V$ are disjoint open sets whose union is $X$. One of them has to contain $v$; let that one be $U$. Now consider $S_n$ for any $n\ge 0$; $v\in S_n$, so $U\cap S_n\ne\varnothing$. But $S_n$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$ with the usual topology, so it is connected, and therefore $V\cap S_n=\varnothing$. And that’s true for **every** $n\ge 0$, so $V=\varnothing$, $U=X$, and $U$ and $V$ aren’t a separation of $X$. Thus, $X$ has no separation and is therefore connected.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thnks a lot for this, I have a small question abt $S_n$ being homeomorphic to $[0,1]$ with the usual (I am guessing its standard order topology) topology. How is it? Is it b/c of a topological equivalence and bijection between $S_n$ and $[0,1]$ ? I hope I shouldnt explain this part by showing that its homeomorphic to the closed interval.

Comment: It’s actually fairly easy to write down a homeomorphism between $[0,1]$ and any of the segments $S_n$. For $S_0$ just map $x\in[0,1]$ to $\langle 0,x\rangle\in S_0$. For $S_n$ with $n\ge 1$ note that $S_n$ is the segment of the line $y=1-nx$ for which $0\le x\le\frac1n$, so you can map $x\in[0,1]$ to $\left\langle\frac{x}n,1-x\right\rangle$. These maps are homeomorphisms.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott okay I got it, thanks!!

Comment: Excellent! You’re welcome.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107233/discussion-between-math-is-fun-and-brian-m-scott).

Comment: I’m already doing (or trying to do!) several things at once, so I don’t think that I can manage an extended discussion; do you think that it’s something that we can handle fairly quickly?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure $X$ is actually connected in all topologies. The point is that in all topologies, the subspace topology on each $S_n$ will be Euclidean. If you have two separating open sets $U$ and $V$, then either $v \in U$ or $v \in V$. This means that we can choose $S_n$ so that $U \cap S_n$ and $V \cap S_n$ will be nonempty, which contradicts the fact that $S_n$ is connected in the Euclidean topology.

$\mathbf{Remark} \, 1$ The Euclidean topology is not finer than the railroad topology. To see this, choose $x \in S_0 -\{v\}$. Then there exists an open neighborhood of $x$ in $X$ in the railroad topology that is completely contained in $S_0$. This is not true in the Euclidean topology: Any open ball of radius $\epsilon$ about $x$ will contain a point of some $S_n$, $n \neq 0$, for which $1/n < \epsilon$ is small enough.

$\mathbf{Remark} \, 2$ It's worth noting (and I think this might be where the text is going) that $X$ is not locally connected with respect to the Euclidean topology, but that it is with respect to the other two topologies.

Comment: Where u said that $v \in U$ or $v \in V$, are you referring to a proposition that says: Let $X = U \cup V$ be a separation of $X$. Suppose $Y$ is a connected subset of $X$. Then either $Y \subset U$ or $Y \subset V$ ? Also, $S_n$ is connected in the Euclidean topology, does this mean that $T_s$ is connected ? Just trying to understand your reasoning & arguments b/c some looks direct but most of it looks complicated for me. It would have been great if u wud have shown a direct proof of this.

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun It's just from the fact that $U \cup V=X$. By definition of union, either $v \in U $ or $v \in V$. Assume it's in $V$. If we have a separation of $X$, then by definition $U$ and $V$ are both nonempty. This means that there is some $S_n$ such that $U \cap S_n$ is nonempty. Hence $U \cap S_n$ and $V \cap S_n$ are nonempty (recall $v \in V \cap S_n$) open sets of $S_n$ whose union is $S_n$ and whose intersection is empty.

Comment: okay, got it. What about the other things I asked with that?

Comment: As I said in the answer, all topologies are connected and the same argument works for all of them. If you want a general statement, it would be something like "If $X= \cup_i Y_i$ is a topological space such that $\cap Y_i \neq \emptyset$, then $X$ is connected if every $Y_i$ is connected"

Comment: @leibnewtz...are u saying that Euclidean topology is $T_s$ ? Also, in remark 1, u said that $T_s$ is not finer than $T_r$ which is true b/c I just proved that it is coarser. But I dont know which theorems to refer or show explicitly that $T_r$ (i.e. topology induced on railroad metric) is connected. Also, how to show $T_c$ is connected ?

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun By Euclidean topology on $X$ I mean the subspace topology on $X$ induced by $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the Euclidean topology, which is $T_s$ by definition. The argument that all three of $T_r$, $T_s$, and $T_c$ are connected is the one I gave in my answer and elaborated on in my comments. A similar argument is given in Henno Brandsma's answer

Comment: okay, got you. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In all three topologies, $S_n$ is homeomorphic to a standard interval $[0,1]$, and hence connected, and as all $S_n$ intersect at the top, their union is connected in all of these topologies, by a standard theorem on union of connected subspaces.

Comment: In all three topologies, $S_n$ is homeomorphic to a standard interval $[0,1]$, how do I show this? What I know is: Let $(X, T_X)$ and $(Y, T_Y)$ be topological spaces with bijective function $h : X \to Y$ continuous and open. Then $h$ is a topological equivalence between $X$ and $Y$ and call the underlying bijection of a topological equivalence $h : X \to Y$ a homeomorphism. We say X and Y are homeomorphic. It would be great to help me make use of these propositions to show $S_n$ is homeomorphic. I understood the last part of ur argument. That's something I did.

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun it’s obvious from the definitions.

Comment: @henno....which definitions, the ones which I mentioned earlier or based on definition 0.1 & 0.2 given in the problem ??

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun An explicit homeomorphism can be obtained by projecting each ray $S_n$ onto $[0,1/n]$, and then scaling to get a map to $[0,1]$.