# In which of the three topologies is X locally connected?

Tags: general-topology, locally-connected

[image]

**Question: In which of the three topologies is X locally connected ?**

Below is a link which shows that all the topologies are connected...

[In which of the three topologies is X connected?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3642450/in-which-of-the-three-topologies-is-x-connected)

Below is how I showed that all of them are locally connected.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

It would be great if someone helps me on this. Appreciate your help & support.

Comment: I'd advise you to type out the answers in LateX/Mathjax instead of taking photographs of handwriting.

Comment: Oh yes, and pictures do not  a proof make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Not locally connected at $(0,0)$, using an argument similar to the topologist’s sine curve.
2. Locally connected because locally an interval except at the top, where the same argument that gives connectedness also gives local connectedness.
3. Is a quotient image of a locally connected space, so locally connected.

Comment: For (1), is $T_s$ locally connected other than $(0,0)$ ?? I hope it is locally connected. I didn't know abt topologists sine curve since we didn't do this in class. But I will definitely check with my prof n ask him abt including this. I checked on google abt this n its really an interesting topic.

Comment: I am correct for (2) and (3) then, thanks for verifying my proof.

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun I didn’t look at your attempts. They’re illegible to me and way too long. The argument is a few sentences each. And the Euclidean topology is locally connected outside the $S_0$ for sure. But failure at one point is enough to refute it for the whole space.

Comment: @Henno....but I am supposed to explain everything, that's wat he wrote on the top "complete explanation (or proof)", that's why I did in a long way. "And the Euclidean topology is locally connected outside the $S_0$ for sure."- are u saying that its not locally connected at $(0,0)$ but everywhere else ?

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun It *is* at $(0,1)$ but at $(0,x)$ for $x$ close to $0$ I think local connectedness fails too. It's just easiest to show (IMHO) at $(0,0)$.

Comment: @Henno.......okay, but how to show it using the argument u mentioned ? I don't have an idea about that thing and also I didnt understand much about that topic. Can u pls help me on this?

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun look around. The argument has been given on this site or elsewhere online many times.

Comment: @Henno.....can u pls verify this? Its for showing that $(0,x)$ is not locally connected. Lets take a point $(0,x)$ $x \geq 0$ and take an open set $U$ around $(0,x)$ such that $U$ dosen't contain $v = (0,1)$. This implies there is a ball(B) around $(0,x)$ such that $B \cap X$ is contained in $U$. observe that we can find a point($y$) inside B such that $y$ does not belong to $X$. If we consider the straight line $L$ joining $v =(0,1)$ to $y$ & extend this line $L$ to whole of $\mathbb{R^{2}}$. This line partitions $\mathbb{R^{2}}$ in two disjoint open halves. Turn on to next comment.......

Comment: ........This line partitions $\mathbb{R^{2}}$ \ $L$ in two disjoint open halves call it $U_1$ and $U_2$. Basically $\mathbb{R^{2}}$ = $L \cup U_1 \cup U_2$ where $L$, $U_1$,$U_2$ are pairwise disjoint. Consider the sets $U_1 \cap U$ and $U_2 \cap U$, we can clearly see that these two are disjoint , nonempty and their union is $U$. Therefore, it is clear that these 2 sets are open in $U$. Thus $U$ is disconnected. We can also conclude that no open subset of $U$ can be connected by the same argument & also $L$ dosen't intersect with $U$, => $X$ is not locally connected at $(0,x)$.Pls verify this

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun you need to remark that there are infinitely many parts of different $_n$ close to $(0,x)$; there are points converging to it even. So both parts, left and right of the line $L$ are non-empty, inside $B$. The idea is OK.

Comment: @Henno.....thanks a lot for that, will do that surely. appreciate ur help & support.